# How to access a file present in another drive from C program while executing through DOSBOX TURBO C

Tags: file, dosbox

When I am copying a file in the directory in which a C program is present then it is reading that file but it fails when I am trying to open a file which is present in a different directory. I am executing a C program using Dosbox Turbo C.

Comment: The directory has to be visible from the one you mounted DOSBox in. If the other directory is in an altogether other *path*, then mount it as well (as a different drive, as far as DOSBox is concerned).

Comment: First google hit: http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Drives

Comment: Thanks Jongware for your suggestion it helped me a lot.